# Simulating a Progressbar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to increase the value of a progessbar. When reaching its maximum it should stop. This code should simulate a server call, the user has to wait and the inputs should be disabled.

```js
function serverCall() {
    var container = $("#disabledBackgroundContainer"),
        progressBar = $("#progressBar"),
        duration = 5000,
        currentProgess = 0,
        steps = 1;

    progressBar.prop("max", duration);
    container.css("display", "block");

    currentProgess = setInterval(function () {
        currentProgess += steps;
        progressBar.val(currentProgess);

        if (currentProgess >= duration) {
            clearInterval(currentProgess);
            container.css("display", "none");
        }
    }, steps);
}
```

```css
#disabledBackgroundContainer {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btnDark" onclick="serverCall()">Server Call</button>
        <div id="disabledBackgroundContainer">
            <progress id="progressBar"></progress>
        </div>
```

As you can see, the progessbar never stops and it seems I got a loop in my code. But I don't get the right way to handle this.

Comment: Why do you have "currentProgess = setInterval"? What do you think will happen there?

Comment: `$("#progressBar")` isn't going to select your element as you have `id="#progressBar"`, it should be `id="progressBar"``

Comment: @Robert to increase it once per second

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, sorry ... I'll update my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `currentProgess` for two different things: a timer ID and an incremental number you want to check.

You need to use two different variables for those:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    currentProgess += steps;
    progressBar.val(currentProgess);

    if (currentProgess >= duration) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        container.css("display", "none");
    }
}, steps);
```

Secondly, remove the hash from the HTML `id` property. Should be `id="progressBar"`. The hash only has meaning as a CSS selector (in your code and style section):

```js
function serverCall() {
    var container = $("#disabledBackgroundContainer"),
        progressBar = $("#progressBar"),
        duration = 5000,
        currentProgess = 0,
        steps = 1;

    progressBar.attr("max", duration);
    progressBar.attr("value", 2000);
    container.css("display", "block");

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        currentProgess += steps;
        progressBar.attr('value', currentProgess);

        if (currentProgess >= duration) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            container.css("display", "none");
        }
    }, steps);
}
```

```css
#disabledBackgroundContainer {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btnDark" onclick="serverCall()">Server Call</button>
<div id="disabledBackgroundContainer">
    <progress id="progressBar"></progress>
</div>
```